# Get rid of the Windows-application tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Why I think that the [windows-application](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/windows-application) tag should be deleted:

- It's about Windows software, but this site is for Ubuntu. The only circumstances I could see it
  relating to Ubuntu would be if the OP wants to run a program under Wine, or if the OP wants to
  find an Ubuntu alternative to a Windows application. If it's about Wine then the tag is rather
  redundant since that's all Wine does so using [wine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/wine)[windows-application](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/windows-application) doesn't add anything
  useful to the question. If it's about finding an Ubuntu alternative to a Windows application then it's
  a software-recommendation. The Windows part is irrelvant since the question is actually about what
  the program does, besides tagging a question [software-recommendation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/software-recommendation)[windows-application](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/windows-application) would
  suggest the OP is looking for a Windows application, which would be off topic.
- There are currently only 5 questions using the [windows-application](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/windows-application). 4 are about wine so the tag is redundant, and other is 
  about running the Ubuntu One Windows client on Windows. Aside from the fact that Canonical (the makers of Ubuntu)
  own the Ubuntu One cloud service it has nothing to do with Ubuntu making it off topic. On top of that 
  Ubuntu One is dead. None of these 5 questions are benifitting from the use of the [windows-application](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/windows-application)
  or providing compelling examples of it's use.

Comment: A new user of Ubuntu might not even know about wine and are unlikely to use that tag if that's the case. Just a thought.

Comment: @ElderGeek A valid point that provides insight into why the tag was made and which audience is using it, but is that something we want promote? The OP's lack of knowledge doesn't change what the question or answers will really be about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, nobody against so I went ahead and removed the tag. This is now [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).